# Replace special unicode characters with normal letters

Tags: python, json, unicode

In my JSON data, there are special Unicode characters like **"\u00E0", "\u00FB"** and so on. I would like to replace all such characters with the normal letters. For example, **"\u00E0"** with **"à"** and **"\u00FB"** with **"û"**. There are a lot of such characters, so I would find a list of them.

I've already tried to replace it with

```
dictData.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

and

```
dictData.replace("\u00E0", "à").replace("\u00E4", "ä").replace("\u00E2", "â").replace("\u00E7", "ç").replace("\u00E8", "è").replace("\u00E9", "é").replace("\u00EA", "ê").replace("\u00EB", "ë").replace("\u00EE", "î").replace("\u00EF", "ï").replace("\u00F4", "ô").replace("\u00F6", "ö").replace("\u00F9", "ù").replace("\u00FB", "û").replace("\u00FC", "ü").replace("\u00FC", "ù").replace("\u00FB", "û").replace("\u00FC", "î").replace
```

But both didn't work. Here is my code

```
import re, sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

patternScript = re.compile("""<script>window\.\_\_WEB\_CONTEXT\_\_\=\{pageManifest:(.*?)\};</script>""", re.DOTALL)

with urlopen("https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html") as response:
    source = str(response.read())
    dictData = patternScript.search(source).group(1).replace('\\ "', '\\"').replace('\\"', '\"').replace("\'", "\\'")
    dictData2 = dictData.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
    #dictData2 = dictData.replace("\u00E0", "à").replace("\u00E4", "ä").replace("\u00E2", "â").replace("\u00E7", "ç").replace("\u00E8", "è").replace("\u00E9", "é").replace("\u00EA", "ê").replace("\u00EB", "ë").replace("\u00EE", "î").replace("\u00EF", "ï").replace("\u00F4", "ô").replace("\u00F6", "ö").replace("\u00F9", "ù").replace("\u00FB", "û").replace("\u00FC", "ü")

    jsonData = json.loads(dictData2)
```

And here is example of JSON data:

```
[{'long': 'Z\\u00FCrich, Schweiz', 'text': 'Lieber Gast\\n\\nDanke f\\u00FCr die nette R\\u00FCckmeldung zu Ihrem Aufenthalt im Hotel Coronado.  Sch\\u00F6n, konnten Sie die Tramstation Milchbuck gleich gegen\\u00FCber des Hotels, mit  direkten Verbindungen ins Stadtzentrum und zum Flughafen Z\\u00FCrich f\\u00FCr sich nutzen.\\n\\nWir freuen uns auf Ihren n\\u00E4chsten Aufenthalt und verbleiben mit\\n\\nHerzlichen Gr\\u00FCssen \\n\\nOlivia Olgiati\\n\\n'}]
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If I run your `'unicode_escape'` attempt (after replacing the single quotes for double quotes), I get it to work by removing the newline characters, which is what it's reporting it's failing on.

Comment: So, first you run dictData = patternScript.search(source).group(1).replace('\\ "', '\\"').replace('\\"', '\"').replace("\'", "\\'") and then something like dictData2 = dictData.decode('unicode_escape').replace("\n", "") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully it works for you:

```
with urlopen("https://www.tripadvisor.ch/Hotel_Review-g188113-d228146-Reviews-Coronado_Hotel-Zurich.html") as response: 
    source = response.read()
    dictData = patternScript.search(source.decode("utf-8")).group(1)
    jsonData = json.loads(dictData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For me worked .decode("unicode_escape")

Comment: @alise I think such kind of replacement is not a good idea, so if my example works for you, it will be better for everyone who will you use your script :)